# How do I add image to RSS Feed Yahoo Weather

Tags: android, image, rss, yahoo, weather

does anyone know how to get the image from Yahoo weather and display it on the android?
The Image that I'm using and the website that I'm using to retrieve the weather is
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1062617&u=c

It is in RSS format. 
I'm able to retrieve the weather information, however, I couldn't retrieve the image of the weather. May I know is there any ways to retrieve it?
I'm a newbie to android and I'm using Eclipse.

I would need your kind advice.
Thank you

MainActivity.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 TextView weather;

 class MyWeather{
  String description;
  String city;
  String region;
  String country;



  String conditiontext;
  String conditiondate;

  String numberOfForecast;
  String forecast;

  public String toString(){

   return "\n- " + description + " -\n\n"
    + "city: " + city + "\n"
    + "region: " + region + "\n"
    + "country: " + country + "\n\n"



    + "Condition: " + conditiontext + "\n"
    + conditiondate +"\n"

    + "\n"
    + "number of forecast: " + numberOfForecast + "\n"
    + forecast;

  } 
 }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        weather = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weather);

        Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

   @Override
   public void run() {
    String weatherString = QueryYahooWeather();
          Document weatherDoc = convertStringToDocument(weatherString);

          final MyWeather weatherResult = parseWeather(weatherDoc);
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

     @Override
     public void run() {
      weather.setText(weatherResult.toString());
     }});

   }});
        myThread.start();
    }

    private MyWeather parseWeather(Document srcDoc){

     MyWeather myWeather = new MyWeather();

     //<description>Yahoo! Weather for New York, NY</description>
     myWeather.description = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("description")
       .item(0)
       .getTextContent();



     //<yweather:condition.../>
     Node conditionNode = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:condition").item(0);
     myWeather.conditiontext = conditionNode.getAttributes()
       .getNamedItem("text")
       .getNodeValue()
       .toString();
     myWeather.conditiondate = conditionNode.getAttributes()
       .getNamedItem("date")
       .getNodeValue()
       .toString();

     //Added to get elements of <yweather:forecast.../>
     NodeList forecastList = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("yweather:forecast");

     myWeather.forecast = "";
     if(forecastList.getLength() > 0){
      myWeather.numberOfForecast = String.valueOf(forecastList.getLength());
      for(int i = 0; i < forecastList.getLength(); i++){
       Node forecastNode = forecastList.item(i);
       myWeather.forecast +=
         forecastNode
          .getAttributes()
          .getNamedItem("date")
          .getNodeValue()
          .toString() + " " +
         forecastNode
          .getAttributes()
          .getNamedItem("text")
          .getNodeValue()
          .toString() +
         " High: " + forecastNode
             .getAttributes()
             .getNamedItem("high")
             .getNodeValue()
             .toString() +
         " Low: " + forecastNode
             .getAttributes()
             .getNamedItem("low")
             .getNodeValue()
             .toString() + "\n";
      }
     }else{
      myWeather.numberOfForecast = "No forecast";
     }

     return myWeather; 
    }

    private Document convertStringToDocument(String src){

     Document dest = null;
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
       DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder parser;

     try {
      parser = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      dest = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(src.getBytes())); 
     } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     }

     return dest; 
    }

    private String QueryYahooWeather(){

     String qResult = "";
     String queryString = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1062617&u=c";

     HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(queryString);

     try {
      HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

      if (httpEntity != null){
       InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
       Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
       BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

       String stringReadLine = null;

       while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n"); 
       }

       qResult = stringBuilder.toString(); 
      } 
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
     }

     return qResult; 
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >




    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/weather"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you