# How to solve the force close error for google weather API

Tags: android, weather

May I know why the weather didn't display after I type in the location?
After I press enter, it gave me force close error.
I'm getting the weather information from google weather API.

Below are my codes.

MainActivity.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 class ForecastInformation{
  String city;
  String postal_code;
  String forecast_date;
  String current_date_time;
  String unit_system;
 }

 class CurrentConditions{
  String condition;
  String temp_f;
  String temp_c;
  String humidity;
  String icon;
  String wind_condition;
 }

 class ForecastConditions{
  String day_of_week;
  String low;
  String high;
  String icon;
  String condition;
 }

 ForecastInformation forecastInformation;
 CurrentConditions currentConditions;
 List<ForecastConditions> forecastConditionsList;

 Button buttonEnter;
 EditText edittextPlace;
 ImageView iconCurrent;
 TextView textCurrent;
 TextView textInfo;
 ListView listForcast;


   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       buttonEnter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
    edittextPlace = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.place);
       iconCurrent = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iconcurrent);
       textCurrent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textcurrent);
       textInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textinfo);
       listForcast = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listforcast);

       buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(EnterOnClickListener);

   }

   Button.OnClickListener EnterOnClickListener
   = new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   String place = edittextPlace.getText().toString();

   String weatherString = QueryGoogleWeather(place);
         Document weatherDoc = convertStringToDocument(weatherString);

         if(parseGoogleWeather(weatherDoc)){
          //Display Result
          String c = currentConditions.condition + "\n"
            + currentConditions.temp_f + "f\n"
            + currentConditions.temp_c + "c\n"
            + currentConditions.humidity + "\n"
            + currentConditions.wind_condition + "\n";

          textCurrent.setText(c);
          Bitmap bm = LoadIcon(currentConditions.icon);
          iconCurrent.setImageBitmap(bm);

          textInfo.setText("city: " + forecastInformation.city + "\n"
            + "postal code: " + forecastInformation.postal_code + "\n"
            + "forecast date: " + forecastInformation.forecast_date + "\n"
            + "current date time: " + forecastInformation.current_date_time + "\n"
            + "unit: " + forecastInformation.unit_system);

       listForcast.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(
               MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.row,
                forecastConditionsList));
         }


  }

   };

   public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ForecastConditions> {

  public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
    List<ForecastConditions> objects) {
   super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
   // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
   View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
   ImageView iconForecast = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.iforecast);
   TextView textForecast = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tforecast);


   textForecast.setText(
     forecastConditionsList.get(position).day_of_week + "\n"
     + " - " + forecastConditionsList.get(position).condition + "\n"
           + forecastConditionsList.get(position).low + " ~ "
           + forecastConditionsList.get(position).high);

   Bitmap bm = LoadIcon(forecastConditionsList.get(position).icon);
   iconForecast.setImageBitmap(bm);

   return row;
  }

   }

   private Bitmap LoadIcon(String iconURL)
   {      
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
       bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
       String image_URL = "http://www.google.com" + iconURL;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;      
    try {
     in = OpenHttpConnection(image_URL);
     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, bmOptions);
     in.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    }
    return bitmap;    
   }

   private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException{
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    try{
     HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
     httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     httpConn.connect();

     if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
      inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream(); 
     } 
    }catch (Exception ex){
    }
    return inputStream; 
   }

   private boolean parseGoogleWeather(Document srcDoc){

    boolean result = false;

    forecastInformation = new ForecastInformation();
    currentConditions = new CurrentConditions();

    //-- Get forecast_information
    NodeList forecast_information = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("forecast_information");
    if (forecast_information.getLength() > 0){

     //Assume place found if "forecast_information" exist
     result = true;

     NodeList infoChilds = forecast_information.item(0).getChildNodes();     

        for(int i=0; i<infoChilds.getLength(); i++){
         Node n = infoChilds.item(i);

         String nName = n.getNodeName();
         String nValue
          = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("data").getNodeValue().toString();
         if (nName.equalsIgnoreCase("city")){
          forecastInformation.city = nValue;
         }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("postal_code"))){
          forecastInformation.postal_code = nValue;
         }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("forecast_date"))){
          forecastInformation.forecast_date = nValue;
         }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("current_date_time"))){
          forecastInformation.current_date_time = nValue;
         }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("unit_system"))){
          forecastInformation.unit_system = nValue;
         }
        }
    }

    //-- Get current_conditions
    NodeList current_conditions = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("current_conditions");
    if(current_conditions.getLength()>0){
     NodeList currentChilds = current_conditions.item(0).getChildNodes();

        for(int i=0; i<currentChilds.getLength(); i++){
         Node n = currentChilds.item(i);

         String nName = n.getNodeName();
         String nValue
          = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("data").getNodeValue().toString();
         if (nName.equalsIgnoreCase("condition")){
          currentConditions.condition = nValue;
         }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("temp_f"))){
          currentConditions.temp_f = nValue;
         }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("temp_c"))){
          currentConditions.temp_c = nValue;
         }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("humidity"))){
          currentConditions.humidity = nValue;
         }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("icon"))){
          currentConditions.icon = nValue;
         }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("wind_condition"))){
          currentConditions.wind_condition = nValue;
         }
        }
    }

    //-- Get forecast_conditions
    NodeList forecast_conditions = srcDoc.getElementsByTagName("forecast_conditions");
    if (forecast_conditions.getLength()>0){
     int forecast_conditions_length = forecast_conditions.getLength();

        forecastConditionsList = new ArrayList<ForecastConditions>();

        for(int j=0; j<forecast_conditions_length; j++){

         ForecastConditions tmpForecastConditions = new ForecastConditions();

         NodeList forecasrChilds = forecast_conditions.item(j).getChildNodes();

         for(int i=0; i<forecasrChilds.getLength(); i++){

             Node n = forecasrChilds.item(i);

             String nName = n.getNodeName();
             String nValue
              = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("data").getNodeValue().toString();

             if (nName.equalsIgnoreCase("condition")){
              tmpForecastConditions.condition = nValue;
             }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("day_of_week"))){
              tmpForecastConditions.day_of_week = nValue;
             }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("low"))){
              tmpForecastConditions.low = nValue;
             }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("high"))){
              tmpForecastConditions.high = nValue;
             }else if((nName.equalsIgnoreCase("icon"))){
              tmpForecastConditions.icon = nValue;
             }
            }
         forecastConditionsList.add(tmpForecastConditions);
        }
    }

    return result;
   }

   private Document convertStringToDocument(String src){
    Document dest = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
      DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder parser;

    try {
     parser = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   dest = parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(src.getBytes()));
  } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
       e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (SAXException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
       e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
       e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

    return dest;
   }

   private String QueryGoogleWeather(String p){

    String uriPlace = Uri.encode(p);

    String qResult = "";
    String queryString = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?hl=en&weather=" + uriPlace;

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(queryString);

       try {
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

        if (httpEntity != null){
         InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
         Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
         BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
         StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

         String stringReadLine = null;

         while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
          stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n"); 
         }

         qResult = stringBuilder.toString(); 
        }

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
       e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
       e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

       return qResult;
   }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="hello" />
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <Button
         android:id="@+id/enter"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="- Enter -"/>
     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/place"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:gravity="center">
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/iconcurrent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textcurrent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

 </LinearLayout>
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textinfo"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listforcast"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/iforecast"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tforecast"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The google weather API has been deprecated. Google discontinued it. This is why your query returns no result.

Comment: Hi, do  you know how to retrieve  <![CDATA[ in  yahoo weather ?

Comment: Hmm I did create an app once, that used the yahoo weather API, but I can't seem to find it. You can however look on Github; there are some Android projects, that use the yahoo weather API, that might help you: [here](https://github.com/search?q=android+yahoo+weather+&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)

Comment: Hmm , I'm able to get my weather apps working.
however, I would like to retrieve  the image from it but I couldn't do so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670246/how-do-i-add-image-to-rss-feed-yahoo-weather